# Dummy generation from categorical variables

Tags: sas, stata, dummy-variable

How can I create in SAS a dummy variable (coded as 0 or 1) for each value of each single categorical variable in my dataset? As I have many variables I would like to do something like a loop.

In Stata, I would use the following code:

```
foreach var of varlist var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 {
    tabulate `var', gen(`var')
    drop `var'
}
```

Comment: Please provide example data suitable for SAS users.

Comment: does this help you? [sas proc GLMMod](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/02/22/create-dummy-variables-in-sas.html)

Comment: Do the dummy variables also need to be populated with `0` or `1` ?

Comment: Where do you want the dummy variables? In a matrix or data set?

Comment: Why do you need the dummy variables?  With most SAS procedures you can just tell it to treat the existing variable as a CLASS variable and it will automatically create dummy columns in its internal matrix operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are several data transformation techniques you could try.

One method is to use `Proc TABULATE` to collate all the distinct variables values into a data set that is used to generate variable names.

```
%macro DummyVariables(data=, var=, out=, genmode=);

  proc tabulate data=&data out=class_values; 
    class &var;
    table &var;
  run;

  %local dsid index seq &var _type_ varname varvalue p_type_;

  %let p_type_ = 0;

  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(class_values));

  %syscall SET ( dsid );

  data &out;
    set &data;

      length

      %if &genmode=1 %then %do;
        %do index = 1 %to %sysfunc(ATTRN(&dsid,NOBS));
          dummy_&index
        %end;
      %end;

      %if &genmode=2 %then %do;
        %do %while (0 = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid)));
          %let index = %sysfunc(index(&_type_, 1));
          %let varname = %scan(&var,&index);
          %if &_type_ ne &p_type_ %then %let seq=1; %else %let seq=%eval(&seq+1);
          &varname._&seq
          %let p_type_ = &_type_;
        %end;
      %end;

      %if &genmode=3 %then %do;
        %do %while (0 = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid)));
          %let index = %sysfunc(index(&_type_, 1));
          %let varname = %scan(&var,&index);
          %let varvalue = &&&varname;
          "&varname._&varvalue"n
        %end;
      %end;
      4;
  run;

  %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%mend;


%DummyVariables (data=sashelp.class, var=name age sex height weight, out=want1, genmode=1);
%DummyVariables (data=sashelp.class, var=name age sex height weight, out=want2, genmode=2);

options validvarname = any;
%DummyVariables (data=sashelp.class, var=name age sex height weight, out=want3, genmode=3);
```

**mode 1** one numerically suffixed dummy variable for each distinct variable and value;

```
NOTE: Variable dummy_1 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable dummy_2 is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable dummy_58 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable dummy_59 is uninitialized.
```

**mode 2** one numerically suffixed dummy variable for each distinct variable AND value.  Dummy variable names based on original variable names.

```
NOTE: Variable name_1 is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable name_19 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable age_1 is uninitialized.
...

NOTE: Variable age_6 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable sex_1 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable sex_2 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable height_1 is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable height_17 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable weight_1 is uninitialized.
etc ...
```

**mode 3** one value suffixed dummy variable for each distinct variable AND value.  Dummy variable names based on variable names AND values.

```
NOTE: Variable name_Alfred is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable name_William is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable age_11 is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable age_15 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable age_16 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable sex_F is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable sex_M is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable 'height_51.3'n is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable 'height_56.3'n is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable height_69 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable height_72 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable 'weight_50.5'n is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable weight_77 is uninitialized.
...
NOTE: Variable weight_133 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable weight_150 is uninitialized.
```